# Wordpress navigation for grandchildren

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I'm currently using this code (per the codex) to show children on parent pages, and children of the parent pages on their children:

```
<?php if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I would like to add that if on a secondary child page (child's child) to then show it's parent and parent's siblings.

Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
{
    //get the parent post
    $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    //check to see if we have a grandparent
    if($parent->post_parent)
    {
        $page_list = wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of' => $parent->post_parent, 'echo' => false, 'depth' => 1 ) );   
    }
    else
    {
        $page_list = wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->post_parent, 'echo' => false, 'depth' => 1 ) );
    }
}
else
     $page_list = wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'echo' => false, 'depth' => 1 ) );
if ($page_list) { 
?>
<ul>
<?php echo $page_list; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This will check if the post has a parent and then if that post has a parent.  The `$page_list` should be a list of pages of the parent and its siblings.  the `'depth' => 1` tells WordPress to only get one level of pages.  This will stop it from getting the children of those pages

Comment: hmm, how can this work with the code I already have? I need that code for parent and child pages still.. could you show me an example of it all together?